# Techniques to debug issues with swift class in objective c project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

So I am rewriting an open source project that is currently objective c to swift. I figured the best way to tackle this complicated project would be to rewrite and integrate each class one at a time. So I re-wrote my first class and am able to point all of the objective c classes to the swift class and there are no compile errors.

When I go to run the program, it fails. I believe it's because an object is failing to be created. The swiftclass-swift.h file is created, but I did have to add one method in there manually that wasn't getting created automatically. Are there techniques or articles on what would be the best way to debug what the issue could be? Should I just create breakpoints at every call of the new class or is there a better workflow to identify the issue?

I have created breakpoints where the class is being initialized and I don't see anything obvious. Additionally, I tried creating unit tests against the class but those won't run because xcode tries to compile the program before running the tests. Also note that the class works fine in a playground. Any help or information to read will be appreciated.

Here is the class:

```
class DateRange: NSObject, NSCopying {

private var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

var start: NSDate
var end: NSDate
var isEmpty: Bool {
    get {return self.start.self.isEqualToDate(self.end)}
}

init(start: NSDate?, end: NSDate?) {
    self.start = start!
    self.end = end!
    super.init()
}

class func dateRange<DR: DateRange>(start: NSDate?, end: NSDate?) -> DR {
    let dateR = DateRange(start: start, end: end) as! DR

    return dateR
}

func components(unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit, forCalendar calendar: NSCalendar) -> NSDateComponents? {
    self.checkIfValid()

    return calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: self.start, toDate: self.end, options: NSCalendarOptions.WrapComponents)
}

func checkIfValid() {
    assert(self.start.compare(self.end) != .OrderedDescending)
}

func containsDate(date: NSDate) -> Bool {
    self.checkIfValid()

    return date.compare(self.start) != .OrderedDescending || self.end.compare(self.start) != .OrderedDescending
}

func intersectDateRange(range: DateRange?) {
    self.checkIfValid()

    if (range!.end.compare(self.start) != .OrderedDescending || self.end.compare(range!.start) != .OrderedDescending) {
        self.end = self.start
        return
    }

    if self.start.compare(range!.start) == .OrderedAscending {
        self.start = range!.start
    }
    if range!.end.compare(self.end) == .OrderedAscending {
        self.end = range!.end
    }
}

func intersectsDateRange(range: DateRange?) -> Bool {
    if range!.end.compare(self.start) != .OrderedDescending || self.end.compare(range!.start) != .OrderedDescending {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func includesDateRange(range: DateRange?) -> Bool {
    if range!.start.compare(self.start) == .OrderedAscending || self.end.compare(range!.end) == .OrderedAscending { return false
    }
    return true
}

func unionDateRange(range: DateRange?) {
    self.checkIfValid()
    range!.checkIfValid()

    self.start = self.start.earlierDate((range?.start)!)
    self.end = self.end.laterDate((range?.end)!)
}

func enumerateDaysWithCalendar(calendar: NSCalendar?, usingBlock: (day: NSDate?, stop: Bool?) ->()) -> Void {

    let comp: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    comp.day = 1

    var date: NSDate = self.start
    let stop: Bool = false

    while !stop && date.compare(self.end) == .OrderedAscending {
        usingBlock(day: date, stop: stop)
        date = (calendar?.dateByAddingComponents(comp, toDate: self.start, options: NSCalendarOptions.WrapComponents))!
        comp.day += 1
    }
}

func isEqualToDate(range: DateRange?) -> Bool {
    return range == range!.start.isEqualToDate(self.start) && range!.end.isEqualToDate(self.end)
}

// MARK: - NSObject

func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
    return DateRange(start: self.start, end: self.end)
}

override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    var isObject = Bool()
    if self.isEqual(object) {
        isObject = true
    }

    if ((object?.isKindOfClass(DateRange)) != nil) {
        isObject = false
    }
    return isObject
}
}
```

Comment: You didn't mention it so I thought I'd ask, is your bridging-header setup properly?  When you say "it fails" when you run it, is that the entire program fails or just the calls the new class?

Comment: The header is created, I did have to add one method that wasn't getting created. I updated the question.

Comment: Can you describe the failure?

Answer (score 0):

That header is generated each time you compile swift code. It is not something meant to be edited manually. Any edits you did make would be blown away the next time you compile.

What this means is *something* about that declaration is not compatible with objective c. Maybe it uses some swift-only feature (like tuples), or maybe it was marked private so it won't export to the header. Cannot say without actually seeing the declaration.

I would start by modifying the declaration to be simpler until it shows up in the header, and making sure that the objective c code can call it when it shows up.